# can snap handle utf8 text?

Tags: haskell, utf-8, haskell-snap-framework

I find that the snap show the utf-8 encoded text as unreadable characters, the code and results like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import qualified Data.Text as T

...

site :: Snap ()
site =
    ifTop (writeText $ T.pack "hello world! 你好") <|> -- Here is the utf-8 text
    route [ ("foo", writeBS "bar")
          , ("query/:pat", echoHandler)
          ] <|> 
    dir "static" (serveDirectory ".")
```

the output in browser is:

```
hello world! ä½ å¥½
```

I search stackoverflow and find there's a similar question ([How to show utf8 text with snap and heist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931786/how-to-show-utf8-text-with-snap-and-heist)), but it seems does not work. How can I handle this utf-8 problem ?

Comment: there are a couple of things here: is your source-file saved as UTF8? (does GHC understand it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797902/haskell-source-encoding), is the encoding set for snap (see your linked question here), ... have you tried the solution shown by the accepted answer there?

Comment: It looks like your server did send UTF-8 encoded text, but your browser interpreted it as ISO-8859-1. You probably need to set an HTTP content encoding header.

Comment: The answer in the linked question shows how to set the content-type. Isn't this a duplicate?